# Why the application works in Firefox, but breaks in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome, firefox, fetch

We have a web application embedded in an **iframe** inside a portal, and we're in the progress of changing the domain for the portal.
When we test with the new domain, the portal works well in Firefox, but it does not load for Chrome.

One thing I notice in the console is that in both browser, there is a failed API call because of **CORS**. However, in Firefox, it logs `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.` in Chrome: `TypeError: Failed to fetch`.

I wonder if this `CORS Failed to fetch` error could potentially break the application inside iframe in Chrome but not in Firefox? And why is that.

Comment: Without a [mcve] showing the code in question we cannot really say.

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with my Angular web app; will work fine with firefox but then breaks in Chrome, in my case it was because of Adblock extension. Try to disable it and see if the problem is still there.
Whenever Adblock detect some key word in my code like "Ads" it block it.

Answer (score 0):

Sure Chrome and Firefox doesn't have the same behavior to manage iframe.
If this is not due to ad blocker (as suggested above), have a look on https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options and add them the web server that serve the page displayed into the iframe.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).